# How can I call a variable from another script to execute a function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Hi I have a script with name 'script.js' the problem is that I have a lot of functions there, and I need execute this function at the beginning of angular.

```
var appMaster = {

    preLoader: function(){

    }, 
    smoothScroll: function() {

    }
}
```

but I need to call this variable appMaster

```
import '../../assets/js/script.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    appMaster.preLoader();
    appMaster.smoothScroll();
  }
}
```

The error is appMaster no undeclared variable. How can I execute the functions within that other script?

Comment: can you check my answer. it will be working hope this will usefull  for your.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

Create javascript file named as common.js inside the following location in your project assets => js => script.js

**common.js**

```
var comman = (function() {
    return {
        masonryBuild: function() {
            console.log('preLoader');
        }
    }
})(comman || {})
```

open **.angular-cli.json** file then add external javascript file path like below

```
"scripts": [
  "../src/assets/js/comman.js"
]
```

declare script var name in your typescript like :

**component.ts**

```
declare var comman: any;

export class Component {
    ngOnInit() {
        comman.masonryBuild();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need to export the appMaster variable from your script file if you want to use it elsewhere.

```js
export let appMaster = {

    preLoader: function(){

    }, 
    smoothScroll: function() {

    }
};



import {appMaster} from '../../assets/js/script.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    appMaster.preLoader();
    appMaster.smoothScroll();
  }
}
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(2,23): error TS6143: Module 'path/js/script.js' solved to 'path/js/script.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you will like to use export/import statement.

If so then change you script.js and use [**export**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

```
var appMaster = {
  preLoader: function(){}, 
  smoothScroll: function() {}
}
export default appMaster;
```

In the component file use [**import**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```
import anyName from "./path/to/file";
```

Call any function from script.js ,expample

```
anyName.preLoader()
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(2,23): error TS6143: Module 'path/js/script.js' solved to 'path/js/script.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.

Comment: seems trying to import js file .ts file. Please check this link
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15970

Answer (score 0):

```
You can call varibale from anthoer script in Angular application.

Step 1. Create demo.js file in assests/javascript folder.

export function test1(){
    console.log('Calling test 1 function');
}

Step 2. Create demo.d.ts file in assests/javascript folder.

export declare function test1();

Step 3. Use it in your component
//User defined file path
import { test1 } from '../assets/javascript/demo'; 
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log(test1());
  }
}


Note: js and .d.ts file name shoule be same
```